# azure pipeline execute but failed to deploy mule app

Tags: maven, mule, cicd, mule4

I am trying to deploy an app using Azure pipeline

**azure.pipeline.yaml**

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
variables:
- group: Build-Variable-Group
- name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
  value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.m2/repository
- name: MAVEN_OPTS
  value: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'


steps:

- task: CacheBeta@0
  inputs:
    key: pom.xml
    path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
  displayName: Cache Maven local Repo

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: settingsxml
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'settings.xml'

- task: Powershell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        New-Item -Type Directory -Force "${HOME}/.m2"
        Copy-Item -Force "$(settingsxml.secureFilePath)" "${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml"
        
        

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    effectivePomSkip: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'clean install package deploy $(MAVEN_OPTS) -DmuleDeploy -Dserver=$(server) -Denvironment=$(environment) -Dworkers=$(workers) -DworkerType=$(workerType) -Dapp.runtime=$(app.runtime) -Dapp.name=$(app.name)'
    
  
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

but getting this error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Deployment failed
> 2022-06-20T07:15:42.3435274Z     at
> org.mule.tools.verification.cloudhub.CloudHubDeploymentVerification$CloudHubDeploymentVerificationStrategy.lambda$isDeployed$0
> (CloudHubDeploymentVerification.java:56)

even in mule log getting the following error :

> om.mulesoft.ch.services.agent.muleAgent.MuleAgentException:
> {"type":"class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"There
> was an error on the Mule Runtime while deploying the application
> clx-salesforceupsert-ifa. Error: Failed to deploy artifact
> [clx-salesforceupsert-ifa]. SAXException: Can't resolve
> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd,
> A dependency or plugin might be missing"}

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to the problem:

```
Can't resolve http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/salesforce/current/mule-salesforce.xsd, A dependency or plugin might be missing"}
```

The application uses the Salesforce connector but the pom is missing the dependency for it. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.15/salesforce-connector-xml-maven for instructions on how to add it.

This issue is about building the Mule application with Maven without any relationship to the Azure pipeline.